# Visual Studio - Watch Window - Weird values

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, watch

A few of my developers have watch windows that look like the following:

[image: Watch Window Issues]

What settings can I change to turn it normal? If this is normal to some people, I mean turn it to the default C# Settings? I'm not sure why it is looking this way but it is very hard to debug.

Comment: What is weird about them?  The hexadecimal display form?  Something else?

Comment: He Hex display. Can't even see what OuterXML is on an xmlDocument or what the vaules of a collection is. How can that be turned back to a regular display?